# Pole placement in uncontrollable systems with state-feedback.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I am somewhat confused on how the standard form for an uncontrollable system can be used to implement state-feedback on the controllable subspace.

- I understand how to use feedback to achieve pole-placement in completely controllable systems.
- I don't understand how this can then be applied to controllable subspaces of uncontrollable systems.

For example, suppose I have an LTI system with eigenvalues {-1, ,1, 2} where eigenvalues {1, 2} are part of the controllable submatrix while -1 is uncontrollable. How do change the pole-locations for the controllable eigenvalues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you only mentioned state feedback I assume that you are dealing with a system of the following form

$$
\dot{x} = A\,x + B\,u
$$

with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and you want to find a state feedback $u = -K\,x$ such that the dynamics of the controllable parts of the system can be chosen. The entire state $x$ is considered to be known and thus observability does not have to be taken into consideration.

By looking at the controllable and uncontrollable states it is possible to find a [similarity transformation](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/SS2SS.html) which decomposes these states, similar to the [Kalman decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_decomposition) but without also considering the observability. In order to do this you need the [controllability matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability#Continuous_linear_time-invariant_.28LTI.29_systems) $\mathcal{C}$ defined as

$$
\mathcal{C} = \begin{bmatrix}
B & A\,B & \cdots & A^{n-1}B
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

A controllable decomposition can be found using the similarity transformation $T = \begin{bmatrix}T_1 & T_2\end{bmatrix}$, with the columns of $T_1$ having the same span as the controllability matrix and $T_2$ chosen such that $T$ is invertible. In the new coordinates, denoted by $x = T\,\hat{x}$, the dynamics are as follows

$$
\dot{\hat{x}} = \underbrace{T^{-1} A\,T}_{\hat{A}}\,\hat{x} + \underbrace{T^{-1} B}_{\hat{B}}\,u
$$

such that

$$
\hat{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\ 0 & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\hat{B} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
B_1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $A_{11}$ has the same size as the rank of $\mathcal{C}$ and the pair $(A_{11}, B_1)$ is controllable (their associated controllability matrix is full rank). So for this pair you can do pole placement, such that the poles of $A_{11}-B_1\,K_1$ can be chosen arbitrarily. Therefore, $u = -\begin{bmatrix}K_1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \hat{x}$ will place the controllable poles of $\hat{A}$ arbitrarily as well.

By using the definition of $\hat{x}$ it is possible to express this state feedback in terms of $x$ instead, namely $\hat{x} = T^{-1} x$. Or in other words your feedback gain can be found with $K = \begin{bmatrix}K_1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\,T^{-1}$.

---

For example given the system

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 \\
-4 & 0 & -2 \\
-2 & -2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix},
$$

which has the eigenvalues $2$, $-2$ and $4$. This pair has the following controllability matrix

$$
\mathcal{C} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 16 \\
0 & -2 & -12 \\
-1 & -2 & -4
\end{bmatrix},
$$

with has rank 2. It can be shown that its first two columns are linearly independent of each other, so an option for the similarity transformation would be

$$
T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

For the added last column it can be shown that it makes $T$ invertible (full rank). Performing the similarity transformation gives

$$
\hat{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -4 & -4 \\
2 & 6 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
\hat{B} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

such that

$$
A_{11} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -4 \\
2 & 6
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Finding a feedback gain for this pair, which places the poles at $-1$ and $-2$ gives $K_1 = \begin{bmatrix}9 & 24\end{bmatrix}$. So the actual state feedback gain can be calculated with

$$
K = \begin{bmatrix}K_1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\,T^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}9 & -6 & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$

which also places the two controllable poles of $A$, which are initially located at $2$ and $4$, at $-1$ and $-2$ respectively.

Comment: Great answer. The combination of general procedure and an example is very instructive.